# Powershell concatenate comboboxes

Tags: powershell, variables, combobox, active-directory, concatenation

Hello All and thank you for taking the time to read my post.

I am working in Powershell 5.0 with the AD Cmdlets module installed. I am having issues with Comboboxes concatenating. Specifically, I have 2 comboboxes where the first combobox looks at a given OU path in our AD tree and displays, via a drop down menu, the OUs underneath that OU. Sub OUs if you will. That return is represented by variable *$OU* which is then input into the next OU path in the next combobox. Basically I am adding *$OU* to the OU path of the first combobox and then the 2nd combobox displays the sub OUs.

I will submit the part of the code that is having errors, then the full code for your reference:

```
$Floor = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=Desktops,OU=Workstations,OU=PMC,OU=facilities,DC=tenethealth,DC=net' -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)


$FloorDDB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$FloorDDB.location = New-Object system.drawing.size(20, 50)
$FloorDDB.size = New-Object system.drawing.size( 180, 20)
$FloorDDB.Height = 400
$FloorDDB.items.AddRange(@($Floor))

# I have tried convert.tostring as well as just using $OU=$FloorDDB.SelectedItem and
# $OU=$FloorDDB.Text
$OU = convert.tostring($FloorDDB.SelectedItem)
$FloorSelect = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase "OU=$OU,OU=Desktops,OU=Workstations,OU=PMC,OU=facilities,DC=tenethealth,DC=net" -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)
    
    
$DeptDDB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DeptDDB.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20, 125)
$DeptDDB.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 20)
$DeptDDB.Height = 400
$DeptDDB.items.Addrange(@($FloorSelect))
```

The first Combobox, $FloorDDB, works as it should. However, I get this error:

> convert.tostring : The term 'convert.tostring' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, >
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
> included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At H:\Scripts\CurrentProject\Static2DHCP.ps1:32 char:7
>
> - $OU = convert.tostring($FloorDDB.SelectedItem)
> - ```
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (convert.tostring:String) [], > CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

If I take out the convert.tostring and replace with something more direct like *$OU=$FloorDDB.text* I get this error:

> Get-ADOrganizationalUnit : The object name has bad syntax
> At line:25 char:18
>
> - ... rSelect = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBa ...
> - ```
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : >
>     ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADOrganizationalUnit

If I replace the $OU with the actual name everything works fine. So I know my syntax is good its just the variable concatenating is the problem.

Here is the full code:

```
### Purpose of this script is to read a list of PCs and change each PC in that list from static IP to DHCP. DNS server must remain.

# First task is to refer to a list or group. GUI will specify PCs to be target.

Add-type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.size = New-Object System.Drawing.size(400, 300)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.text = "Cancel"
$cancelButton.size = New-Object System.Drawing.size(80,50)
$cancelButton.location = New-object system.drawing.point(250, 150)
$cancelButton.add_click({$form.tag = $form.close()})

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.location = New-Object system.drawing.size(250, 50)
$button.size = New-Object system.drawing.size(80, 50)
$button.text = "Confirm Selection"

$Floor = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=Desktops,OU=Workstations,OU=PMC,OU=facilities,DC=tenethealth,DC=net' -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)


$FloorDDB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$FloorDDB.location = New-Object system.drawing.size(20, 50)
$FloorDDB.size = New-Object system.drawing.size( 180, 20)
$FloorDDB.Height = 400
$FloorDDB.items.AddRange(@($Floor))


$OU = convert.tostring($FloorDDB.SelectedItem)
$FloorSelect = @(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase "OU=$OU,OU=Desktops,OU=Workstations,OU=PMC,OU=facilities,DC=tenethealth,DC=net" -SearchScope OneLevel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)
    
    
$DeptDDB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DeptDDB.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20, 125)
$DeptDDB.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 20)
$DeptDDB.Height = 400
$DeptDDB.items.Addrange(@($FloorSelect))

    

$PCTB= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$PCTB.location = New-Object system.drawing.size(20, 200)
$PCTB.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 20)
$PCTB.Height = 400

$form.controls.add($cancelButton)
$form.controls.add($button)
$form.controls.add($FloorDDB)
$form.controls.add($deptDDB)
$Form.controls.add($PCTB)


#Commented until script is done to avoid annoying loss of network access
#Get-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Enabled


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

In summation:

2 Comboboxes. 1st combobox has the user select a floor OU. The 2nd combobox references the first combobox and displays the departments OU located within that floor OU.

Thank you for your time. Apologize for the wall of text.

Comment: Don't complicate things. Try something like `[string]$FloorDDB.SelectedItem.Text`. If in doubt assign it to a variable and `Write-Host` it to the console to see what kind of object/string you're dealing with

Comment: So I declared ```$OU = [string]$FloorDDB.Text``` and the error messages went away but the 2nd drop down box isnt working correctly. It will display OUs but it will display the wrong ones. It displays whatever floor was selected the LAST time the script was ran. Main problem fixed I need to clear the variable each time. Thanks for the help, I am getting close.

Comment: Read up about powershell variable scoping - I'd suspect it is involved in your second issue. Rememebr that many script editors dont clear variables. The only waty to be sure you havent got any left from last time you ran is to clear them or run in a new window.